# How to find out which function is causing a 404

Tags: 404-error, debug

So I am trying to upgrade a WordPress project and for one section I get the 404 instead of seeing a product page. I looked around and tried adding this to my `functions.php`

```
    add_action('wp_head', 'show_template');
    function show_template() {
        global $template;
        print_r($template);
    }
```

but on the top it just shows me `wordpress-3.5.2/wp-content/themes/mytheme/404.php`. Can anyone teach me how to trace the error? WP_DEBUG_LOG does have a few depracations and stuff but I'm not sure if that's relevant... Is there a systematic way to trace which function is responsible for this?

I'll paste what WP_DEBUG shows just in case:

> Notice: Undefined index: HTTPS in /Users/emai/Documents/wordpress_projects/mytheme/wordpress-3.5.2/wp-content/plugins/audio-player/audio-player.php on line 127
>
> Notice: Undefined index: SERVER_PORT_SECURE in /Users/emai/Documents/wordpress_projects/mytheme/wordpress-3.5.2/wp-content/plugins/audio-player/audio-player.php on line 127
>
> Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /Users/emai/Documents/wordpress_projects/mytheme/wordpress-3.5.2/wp-content/plugins/audio-player/audio-player.php:127) in /Users/emai/Documents/wordpress_projects/mytheme/wordpress-3.5.2/wp-content/plugins/wp-e-commerce/wpsc-core/wpsc-constants.php on line 17
>
> Notice: add_custom_background is deprecated since version 3.4! Use add_theme_support( 'custom-background', $args ) instead. in /Users/emai/Documents/wordpress_projects/mytheme/wordpress-3.5.2/wp-includes/functions.php on line 2841
>
> Notice: add_custom_image_header is deprecated since version 3.4! Use add_theme_support( 'custom-header', $args ) instead. in /Users/emai/Documents/wordpress_projects/mytheme/wordpress-3.5.2/wp-includes/functions.php on line 2841
>
> Notice: Undefined index: /js/js_gallery/jquery-1.6.1.min.js in /Users/emai/Documents/wordpress_projects/mytheme/wordpress-3.5.2/wp-includes/class.wp-scripts.php on line 163
>
> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /Users/emai/Documents/wordpress_projects/mytheme/wordpress-3.5.2/wp-includes/class.wp-scripts.php on line 163
> /Users/emai/Documents/wordpress_projects/mytheme/wordpress-3.5.2/wp-content/themes/mytheme/404.php

Comment: First things first -- you're sure the post/page you're trying to view actually exists?  You can see it in the relevant Admin screens?

Comment: How would I check? In production (pre-upgrade) all the product pages exist. The data in the databases should match since I dumped/restored from it

Comment: Go to http://[your-site].com/wp-admin and have a look in the Posts or Pages menu (or if it's a custom post type, the edit screens for your post type).  Also, if it's indeed there, check your permalinks (**Settings > Permalinks**) and save them *even if you don't make any changes*.  This will flush the permalinks, which might be all that's needed.

Comment: .... IT WORKED!! what the heck!!! How did that work?????? I don't remember ever going to that page

Comment: Done.  I also added a bit of explanation. (Other users: if I'm wrong in the details, by all means, correct me.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to http://[your-site].com/wp-admin and have a look in the Posts or Pages menu (or if it's a custom post type, the edit screens for your post type). Also, if it's indeed there, check your permalinks (Settings > Permalinks) and save them even if you don't make any changes. This will flush the permalinks, which might be all that's needed.

**How it works:** If you did a DB dump of your site, and then imported it into another DB, you'll get all the posts/pages/sundry other content, but your Permalinks need to be flushed to make sure that WordPress understands that a request from the browser for, say, '/products/acme-widgets/foo' is really a request for the post with `$post->ID` 39.  If you make changes to the permalink structure, the permalinks need to be flushed.  This doesn't happen automatically because it's an intensive process.

Saving your Permalinks does a flush.